# How to translate this working SQL statement to JPA CriteriaBuilder?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, join

I have three tables: Company, Share and Shareholders. Share is a junction table between Company and Shareholder.

I want to be able to extract (show in UI) only these Companies, for which a Shareholder with given security_id has an access/share.

My problem is that I don't know how to translate my working sql query to a predicate which will be used for searching.

I use Specification interface and PredicateBuilder.

Entities (with only relevant fields):

```
public class Company {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "company_id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")
    private Set<Share> shares;


public class Share {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "share_id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
    private Company company;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "shareholder_id")
    private Shareholder shareholder;

public class Shareholder {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "shareholder_id")
    private Long id;
    
    @Column
    private String securityId;
```

My code in PredicateBuilder class, which gives an empty result:

```
public CompanyPredicateBuilder access(String securityId) {
    Join<Company, Share> joinShare = root.join(Company.PROPERTY_SHAREHOLDERS);
    Join<Share, Shareholder> joinShareholder = joinShare.join(Share.PROPERTY_SHAREHOLDER);
    Predicate predicate = cb.equal(joinShareholder.get(Shareholder.PROPERTY_SECURITY_ID), securityId);

    predicates.add(predicate);

    return this;
}
```

Then a findAll(query.createSpecification) method in repo is called.

And finally the SQL query that works:

```
SELECT
*
FROM company
JOIN share
ON company.company_id = share.company_id
JOIN shareholder
ON share.shareholder_id = shareholder.shareholder_id
WHERE
shareholder.security_id = 'example'
```

Any help will be appreciated... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using a wrong property here, but I can't really see what is behind these constants: `root.join(Company.PROPERTY_SHAREHOLDERS);`.

Why aren't you using the static metamodel generated by Hibernate to avoid such issues and at the same time be more type safe?

Comment: thanks for the answer! I've just noticed there was a mistake in Company class code snippet above. I edited it and now i am sure it's ok. 

Regarding these constants - I use static final Strings in entities which point to certain fields inside, for example::

public static final String PROPERTY_CURRENT_PROJECT_ID = "currentProjectId";

points to:

private Project currentProjectId;

in the same class

Comment: The first join with these constant you mentioned is working fine. I can create a predicate and it works ok. The problem is when I want to join the third table to already created Join. Then i get an empty result...

Comment: What is the SQL that is generated vs what you expect?

Comment: It's actually interesting, because it is exactly the same, though it returns nothing

Comment: generated SQL:
select distinct company0_.company_id as company_id1_23_, (...and all of the fields...) from public.company company0_ inner join public.share shares1_ on company0_.company_id=shares1_.company_id inner join public.shareholder shareholder1_ on share0.shareholder_id=shareholder1_.shareholder_id where shareholder1_.security_id=? limit ?

Comment: If the query is the same, the parameter values must be different or the transaction visibility ;)